# Kafka consumer on single core CPU

Tags: multithreading, kubernetes, apache-kafka

I have a kafka topic with 20 partitions and 20 kafka consumers from single consumer group id.
I run my application in kubernetes pod and each pod has two kafka consumer threads, so overall 10 pods each having two consumers. Application is running normal.
But each of these kube pods has only single core (CPU) assigned. Now i started to think if running two consumer threads per pod would really gives the best performance compared to if downsize the consumer thread to 1 per pod since CPU is single core. If it's a multi core kube pod then the two consumer threads would have benefited from parallelism.
Any thoughts on how single core CPU would affect the performance??

Question is about 2 kafka consumer threads per single core CPU pod vs 1 kafka consumer thread per single core CPU pod

Comment: Java threads are not OS threads. And OS threads are not hardware cores. Even if we had only a single hardware core, we can still use concurrency. And this can also result in improved performance. For the specific case... testing and benchmarking it might be the fastest and most reliable way to answer the question.

Comment: Related - https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer

Comment: When you say "single core assigned", what exactly are you configuring to do this?  How is it actually related to Kubernetes?  Have you actually measured your system performance; are you seeing observable bottlenecks in message throughput?

Comment: @DavidMaze - Its basically a VM on which the kube pods spin off and when they gets created, each pods is assigned a single core and around 2gig memory. I was thinking if the core has really has anything to limit the number of consumers. In a time slicing CPU scheduling would the parallelism be really achieved if I use single kafka consumer vs more than one ??

Answer (score 0):

Kafka consumer is not thread-safe, it is best to avoid having multiple threads trying to access the same consumer instead. If you still want to design in such way, then you refer the following ( @OneCricketeer also mentioned the same).

https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer

From the KAFKA Eco System adoption perspective, this is what community recommends

Processing power is not as important as disk and memory, but it will affect overall
performance of the broker to some extent. Ideally, clients should compress messages
to optimize network and disk usage. The Kafka broker must decompress all message
batches, however, in order to validate the checksum of the individual messages and
assign offsets. It then needs to recompress the message batch in order to store it on
disk. This is where the majority of Kafka’s requirement for processing power comes
from. This should not be the primary factor in selecting hardware, however.

Comment: @chrisdist - My intention is to have single consumer assigned for each partition so it doesn't really come under multi threading as each consumer is assigned a thread. However does it matters the number of such consumers in each CPU (in my case they are single core CPU's)? Like having one consumer per CPU vs having more than like 2 consumers per CPU